# Multi tenant notifications with noticed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use [Noticed](https://github.com/excid3/noticed) gem with [ActAsTenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) gem, but it does not work.
I followed Chris Oliver tutorial on YouTube.

but I got this error, when I use act as tenant:

```
uninitialized constant PropertyNotification::Current
```

Notifications model:

```
belongs_to :account
acts_as_tenant :account
```

In `PropertyNotification < Noticed::Base`

```
def to_database
    {
      type: self.class.name,
      params: params,
      account: Current.account
    }
end
```